# VM error while starting Wildfly (JBoss) server

Tags: java, jboss

I have wildfly-10.0.0.Final available with PATH variable set. I am using Ubuntu. Also I have jdk1.7.0_79. I am facing the problem that as when I am trying to start server that is executing standalone.sh then I am getting the error,

`Unrecognized VM option 'MetaspaceSize=96M'`

`Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.`

`Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

Comment: you can change the VM options in wildfly/bin/standalone.conf

Comment: I'm getting this error when I'm trying to compile a java 7 code when I have java 8 installed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use jdk 1.8 instead of jdk 1.7. MetaspaceSize is a new flag added for Metaspace in jdk 1.8.

Comment: If you want to keep the current java version and use jdk 1.8 only for wildfly you can open standalone.conf.bat file in wildfly-10.0.0.Final\bin\ folder and uncomment the line with set "JAVA_HOME=C:\opt\jdk1.6.0_23" and change to ur location.

Comment: @nanospeck thanks this is great not to break your current JAVA_HOME config

Comment: After change java to 1.8 wildfly 10.1.0 also server works fine !!

Comment: @Lukasz: Thanks. Saved the day!

Answer (score 1):

Check java -version. If it is not *java version "1.8.0_xx"*, then set the JAVA_HOME environment variable as below and run the command,

bash-4.1$ export JAVA_HOME=LOCATION_TO_JDK1.8.0

Answer (score -1):

You have to put in the standalone.bat file this line set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4, and change the ubication of the JDK installation.